# non-existent files in Windows Documents folder

Tags: windows, documents

I just stumbled across a few files in my Documents folder viewing it in a bash shell (but also shows in windows cmd). What are these? They do not show (even as hidden) in the file explorer.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are files with the `system file` attribute. To show them in explorer you need to untick folder option `Hide protected operating system files` (and since they usually have the `hidden file` attribute as well, so you need to switch to the folder option `Show hidden files, folders, and drives` *additionally*):

[image]

See also: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490868.aspx